# Need help implementing a SmartPointer

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

I'm having trouble implementing a smart pointer in C++ for an assignment.
My code is supposed to create two SmartPointers. The first points to 1 and the second initially points to 3 but is changed to 10. My code should print out

intOne: 1
intTwo: 10

but instead it prints out

intOne: 10
intTwo: 4919984

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
public:
    SmartPointer(T in)
    {
        try
        {
            if(in<0)
            {
                throw "SmartPointer does not handle negative numbers";
            }
            T * val = &in;
            this->data = val;
        }
        catch(exception& e)
        {
            cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
    ~SmartPointer()
    {
        delete data;
    }
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T val);
private:
    T*data;
};

template <typename T> T SmartPointer<T>::getValue()
{
    return *this->data;
}

template <typename T> void SmartPointer<T>::setValue(T val)
{
    if(val<0)
    {
        throw "SmartPointer does not handle negative numbers";
    }
    this->data = &val;
}

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<int> intOne(1);
    SmartPointer<int> intTwo(3);
    intTwo.setValue(10);
    cout<<"intOne: "<<intOne.getValue()<<endl;
    cout<<"intTwo: "<<intTwo.getValue()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why setting `&val` which is address of val?

Comment: `T * val = &in;` you just set the internal pointer to a local variable which is destroyed upon the constructor returning.

Comment: I tried something like *data = val but that makes it crash after compiling @Eljay

Comment: You never allocated the memory to store the number 1 and 3... Pointers don't store numbers.

Comment: I think your main() should begin with something more like:  SmartPointer<int> onePtr(new int(1));   ... i.e. your SmartPointer is (presumably) supposed to be managing the lifetime of a heap-allocated object (in this case, a heap-allocated int), not holding an int directly by-value.

Comment: Just a tip, you throw an exception in setValue() might as well try { catch { in main when you call it....

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor takes a T by value and then attempts to set the internal pointer to the local copy of the value. It should take the address of a T instead.

Your exception stuff is unnecessary, since the class doesn't even know what type is T, so it could be some type that does not have a comparison operator with an int. Even if you do need to throw exceptions, they should be caught in `main()`, since nobody expects a constructor to print error messages to the screen. `throw "message"` is wrong, since you're trying to throw an instance of `const char*`. Instead, call the constructor of one of the standard exceptions like `throw domain_error("message")`.

Using `this->` does not really do anything other than make it slower to type.

In case you didn't know, using `endl` flushes the buffer. If you don't need it, use '\n'.

The fixed code:

```
//#include <stdio.h> Why?
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
public:
    SmartPointer(T *in);
    ~SmartPointer();
    T getValue();
    void setValue(const T &val);
private:
    T *data;
};

template<typename T> SmartPointer<T>::SmartPointer(T *in) //Moved implementation outside of class declaration
{
    //Completely unnecessary exception stuff
    data = in; //this-> is unnecessary
}

template<typename T> SmartPointer<T>::~SmartPointer()
{
    delete data;
}

template<typename T> T SmartPointer<T>::getValue()
{
    return *data;
}

template<typename T> void SmartPointer<T>::setValue(const T &val)
{
    //More unnecessary exception stuff
    *data = val;
}

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<int> intOne(new int); //The constructor should take a pointer for the object to store instead of an value
    SmartPointer<int> intTwo(new int);
    intOne.setValue(1);
    intTwo.setValue(10);
    cout << "intOne: " << intOne.getValue() << '\n'; //endl flushes the buffer, kind of unnecessary here
    cout << "intTwo: " << intTwo.getValue() << '\n'; //since it gets flushed upon the program exiting anyways
}
```